# Which versions of Ubuntu support ARM?

Tags: arm

The official website made this unclear. I have been having problems with running executable files on the BPI image of Mate so I'd like to just use an official version so that I don't encounter problems like this. Are there any versions that work on these processors? (I use a 32-bit A7 processor)

Comment: I'm talking about the different versions, not servers. (mate , lubuntu, etc)

Comment: All downloads that have "arm" in it And the server is the base of ALL versions ;-) Like http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/zesty/main/installer-arm64/current/images/netboot/ does. Btw you need 64-bit I would assume. Doubt we have a 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These versions of Ubuntu support ARM.

```
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm  
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi  
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started
```

Comment: Most ARM versions of Ubuntu seem to be 64-bit only. Sadly, I have 32-bit as my single-board computer only have 2GB of RAM and doesn't really need 64-bit. Because of this and other problems I'm facing with the OS, I'm switching over to Open SUSE as it's more fitting for how I use computers and support my board specifically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

32-bit ARM support appears to have been or is being discontinued. All I can find currently are pre-installed server images for the Raspberry Pi, available [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) As time goes by 32-bit options are disappearing. I recommend seeking out 64-bit alternatives. [This old Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71828/what-arm-single-board-computers-does-are-supported-by-ubuntu?rq=1) reflects some of the history of  this. [Phoronix reported back in May of 2018 that armhf was proposed to be on the chopping block.](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ARMHF-Ubuntu-Chopping-Block) If you are still running on 32-bit hardware you will find your options more and more limited as time goes by. There was a great deal of discussion topic on [the developers mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2018-May/subject.html#start) under the topic Proposal: Let's drop i386. [Desktop images such as you mention have already been dropped from development for 32-bit.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-32-bit-builds-dropped)